# C# Windows Service Timeout on startup

Tags: c#, windows, service, timeout, log4net

I'm having difficulty trying to determine the cause of a timeout in a Windows Service I've created with C#.
I've spent a considerable amount of time looking at several posts and topics on the issue but I am unsure what else to try.

**What's the problem?**

Sometimes on certain machines which run my windows service, it does not start successfully after the machine has been rebooted.
I receive the common EventLog messages about the Service failing to start in a timely fashion and that it timed out after 30000 milliseconds.
Windows Server 2003 machines seem to be the most common pattern but is not always isolated to just this OS. For example it works perfectly fine on other W2K3 machines.

The startup failure can be quite random in that sometimes it will start, and other times it will fail so it is very difficult to reproduce the issue on demand.
I am also using Log4Net to catch and errors and log them to a RollingFileAppender. However, when the service fails to start, no log file is ever created and no log information saved.
It is as if my Service entry thread is blocking and not getting called.

**Other Details:**

1. The Windows service is written in C# and uses .Net 2.0
2. There are no other service dependencies for my service when
   installed.
3. The service exe is a Release build with no signing or authenticode
   signing.
4. The OnStart method executes as quickly as possible by creating a
   Thread and starting that Thread. No other initialization takes place
   within OnStart.
5. When the service does actually fail to start, opening the services
   list and starting it manually works every time and the service
   starts in probably less than a second.

I have the following code added to my Program.cs which include the main entry point for the service.
I hook in to an UnhandledException event on the CurrentDomain and am using log4net to log any unhandled errors
There's also a try/catch around the ServiceBase.Run in the event it somehow bombs out so that I can log that error.

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new SchedulerService() 
    };

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

    try
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal("Unhandled Service Exception", ex);
    }
}

private static log4net.ILog _log = null;
static log4net.ILog Log
{
    get
    {
        if (_log == null)
        {
            if (!log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
            {
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            }

            _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
        }
        return _log;
    }
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    if (ex == null) ex = new Exception(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());

    Log.Fatal("Unhandled Service Exception", ex);
}
```

The code in my inherited ServiceBase implementation is as follows:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Thread serviceThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BackgroundStart));
    serviceThread.IsBackground = true;
    serviceThread.Start();
}

private void BackgroundStart()
{
    //Initialize and start worker objects to perform monitoring...
    //<Snip>
}
```

My log4net implementation is using a ConsoleAppender and a RollingFileAppender where its configuration details are stored in the App.config.

At this stage I am not sure what else to try.
If any more details are needed let me know.

Thanks.

**Update:**
Just to update everyone, I'm going to try some of the suggestions such as logging to the EventLog directly or a file instead of Log4Net to see if that's the cause.
I Will also try setting the generatePublisherEvidence in the app.config to false.
I'm just waiting for an appropriate downtime to access the client's server to test these things out.

Comment: Have you tried adding debug statements in your code to know up to what point the service is starting?

Comment: You could also try to enable log4net internal debugging to possibly get a little more info: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#How%20do%20I%20enable%20log4net%20internal%20debugging%3F

Comment: One possibility is that your logging framework is what is hanging and this is hiding the real issue, especially since you say nothing is logged when it hangs.

Comment: Hi, the worker objects I initialize in the BackgroundThread function write to my log4net logger when they are initialized and I call Start() on those worker objects. However it doesn't seems to be reaching this point as no log file is ever created, which would suggest the code in my OnStart isn't starting my thread.

Comment: Yes I am beginning to think it could be an issue with log4net. It seems to be the only external dependency outside of OnStart that is delaying

Comment: The log4net initialization is not thread safe, that's all I see.  Create it in Main().

Comment: Did you come to a conclusion on this? I have the same issue on one of my machines. No log, just timeout.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed similar issue by turning off publisher evidence generation in config file. The service also did not have authenticode signing but adding following line immediately fixed the issue on the machine where it has been reproduced consistently.

```
<runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false" />
</runtime>
```

Also recommended in [this MSDN source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2008/02/29/should-i-authenticode-sign-my-net-assembly.aspx):
"We recommend that services use the  element to improve startup performance. Using this element can also help avoid **delays that can cause a time-out and the cancellation of the service startup**. "

Answer (score 2):

In general, spawning a background thread from `OnStart` is the right thing to do.

For troubleshooting purposes, you could try to give your service more startup time by calling [RequestAdditionalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method from `OnStart`. Also, you might want to check if any messages have been written to the Windows EventLog (log "Application", the source should be your service name).

Answer (score 2):

A few things to try:

- Add log messages to the top of `Main()`, before `ServiceBase.Run()`, etc.  Assuming you get a log file, how do those timestamps compare to the Windows Event Log?
- Create a brand new Service with the New Project Wizard and deploy it as-is.  On the problem machines, does it start reliably?
- Get [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and watch a normal startup.  Look for any unexpected network or file I/O.
- Make sure your `SchedulerService` does not do any work in the constructor, and does not have any statically-initialized dependencies.
- Set the Recovery options to restart on first failure.  Does that work reliably?

Answer (score 1):

I'd also suspect that log4net is somehow hanging. Maybe the drive where the log is to be created is not ready yet when the machine is booting. Have you tried starting your service delayed?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, just found out that this option is only available in Vista and later. But you might want to move the creation of the logger into the Main method and delay the service start yourself until the logger can successfully be created.

Answer (score 0):

Since log4net is not designed to be ([in their words](http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#reliable)) a reliable logging system, I thought it was good practice to write unhandled exceptions to the eventlog (as well as to your log), especially with services.