# Wix installer: installed service unable to read HKLM registry entries on start

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm using wix tool 3.11 to create a msi which install a service. The installer runs a Custom Action and returns vars to wix to write to registry (HKLM). The service starts and try to read the registry but it can't be done and it fails. If I wrote the registry manually the installer works perfectly.

Error message from msi logs:

```
Product: Installer-- Error 1920. Service 'XPTO Server' (xpto_server) failed to start.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.
```

My Wix XML:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />
...
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="CMP_RegistryEntries" Guid="xxxxxxxxx" >
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\XPTOInc\XPTO\XPTOServer\BetaVersion">
      <RegistryValue Name="token" Action="write" Value="[TOKEN]" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
      <RegistryValue Name="[IDENTIFIER_TYPE]" Action="write" Value="[INSTALLEDID]" Type="string" />
      <RegistryValue Name="installDir" Action="write" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" Type="string" />
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="CMP_XPTOServerEXE" Guid="xxxxxx">
    <File Id="FILE_XPTOServerEXE" Name="xpto-server.exe" Source="Work\xpto-server.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
    <ServiceInstall Id="InstallExporterService" Name="xpto_server" DisplayName="XPTO Server" Description="Read data from Registry and do simple stuff" ErrorControl="normal" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" />
    <ServiceControl Id="ServiceStateControl" Name="xpto_server" Remove="uninstall" Start="install" Stop="both" />
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

EDIT: When I manually wrote the vars to Registry, the service installs with msi pkg or running with sc.exe

EDIT 2: Here follows the log where sets the registry and then star service

```
MSI (s) (70:74) [15:40:37:560]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 16808 (0x41A8).
MSI (s) (70:E4) [15:40:37:613]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (70:E4) [15:40:37:615]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated Non-remapped custom action server.
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:973]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=WriteRegistryValues,Description=Writing system registry values,Template=Key: [1], Name: [2], Value: [3])
Action 15:40:37: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:974]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=3,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=13200)
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:975]: Executing op: RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=SOFTWARE\XPTOInc\XPTO\XPTOServer\BetaVersion,,BinaryType=0,,)
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:975]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=token,Value=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,)
WriteRegistryValues: Key: \SOFTWARE\XPTOInc\XPTO\XPTOServer\BetaVersion, Name: token, Value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:976]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=envId,Value=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,)
WriteRegistryValues: Key: \SOFTWARE\XPTOInc\XPTO\XPTOServer\BetaVersion, Name: envId, Value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:976]: Executing op: RegAddValue(Name=installDir,Value=C:\Program Files (x86)\XPTOInc\XPTO\XPTO Server Beta\,)
WriteRegistryValues: Key: \SOFTWARE\XPTOInc\XPTO\XPTOServer\BetaVersion, Name: installDir, Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\XPTOInc\XPTO\XPTO Server Beta\
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:977]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=InstallServices,Description=Installing new services,Template=Service: [2])
Action 15:40:37: InstallServices. Installing new services
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:977]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=1,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=1300000)
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:978]: Executing op: ServiceInstall(Name=xpto_server,DisplayName=XPTOServer,ImagePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\XPTOInc\XPTO\XPTO Server Beta\xpto-server.exe",ServiceType=16,StartType=2,ErrorControl=1,,Dependencies=[~],,,Password=**********,Description=Read data from Registry and do simple stuff,,)
InstallServices: Service: 
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:980]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=StartServices,Description=Starting services,Template=Service: [1])
Action 15:40:37: StartServices. Starting services
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:981]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=1,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=1300000)
MSI (s) (70:38) [15:40:37:981]: Executing op: ServiceControl(,Name=xpto_server,Action=1,,)
StartServices: Service: XPTO Server
Error 1920. Service 'XPTO Server' (xpto_server) failed to start.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution***: The problem in this case was that the registry keys were not found in the expected location in the registry due to 32-bit / 64-bit issues.

- **64-bit section**: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\App` - `MyValue`
- **32 bit section**: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Company\App` - `MyValue`

***End of answer***. Leaving debugging efforts in place below though:

---

***Round 1***:

Maybe try to read these two recent answers and check if anything rings a bell:

- [Wix Service Installer sometimes fails to install or start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292664/wix-service-installer-sometimes-fails-to-install-or-start/50298423#50298423)
- [Wix - ServiceControl start takes four minutes to fail, should be 30 sec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340129/wix-servicecontrol-start-takes-four-minutes-to-fail-should-be-30-sec/50354019#50354019)

What does it say in **the event viewer**? (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> `eventvwr` and `OK`)

---

***Round 2***:

- ***Bitness***: Are  you sure you are reading from the **right location in the registry**? Are you installing a 32-bit MSI or a 64-bit MSI? (looks like 32-bit)

  - **64-bit section**: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\App`
  - **32 bit section**: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Company\App`
- ***Permissions***: Did you check the **permissions** for the registry keys and values your setup writes using `regedit.exe` to inspect? `Right click => Permissions` (have to ask).
- ***Privileges***: What account do you use to run the service? It sort of looks like standard LocalSystem? The account needs the [SeServiceLogonRight](https://ss64.com/nt/ntrights.html) privilege. See second line on section above for details.
- ***Logging***: Do you use **log4net** or some other logging feature in your service? Did you try the **verbose, debug MSI logging** found in the first link in the top section?

Comment: Event Viewer just say this message: The XPTOServer service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. This only happen when my service couldn't read registry values

Comment: @LucasBlaschiGameiro - Added some more suggestions. Please have a look.

Comment: It was the 32bit issue. It is working perfectly now! thanks

Comment: OK, let me add a summary at the beginning since the answer became a little too messy.